# How to pack an additional symbols.nupkg with new csproj VS2017

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2017, csproj

With the new `csproj` format in **Visual Studio 2017**, it makes it really easy to build nuget packages. If fact, in properties on the project file gives you a gui and you can enter all the nuget info so its just a click away to pack.

However there are no options in the gui to build a *symbols.nupkg* that includes the source and PDB for a nuget debugging server.

How can I use this new feature in VS2017 and still create a *symbols.nupkg*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accepted answer is valid because it's dated in Mar,2017.

Symbol packages is becoming legacy. symbols.nupkg is still supported but only for [compatibility reasons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/symbol-packages).

The new recommended format for symbol packages is .snupkg
Add the following lines in csproj file in vs 2017 :

```
   <PropertyGroup>
     <IncludeSymbols>true</IncludeSymbols>
     <SymbolPackageFormat>snupkg</SymbolPackageFormat>
   </PropertyGroup>
```

for more details review: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/symbol-packages-snupkg

Answer (score 27):

Just edit your new `csproj` and inside the `PropertyGroup` tags add Tags for `IncludeSource` and `IncludeSymbols` like below. Pack in VS2017 will then make an additional *symbols.nupkg*.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <IncludeSource>True</IncludeSource>
    <IncludeSymbols>True</IncludeSymbols>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

To see the whole list of tags available for Nuget package building in the new csproj you can refer to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#nuget-metadata-properties)

Comment: If I had tried doing yesterday what I'm trying to do today, I'd have been stumped on this. Great timing!

Comment: The docs link is a 404.  Does anyone know where it was moved?  I'd really like to see that list of available tags.

Comment: It wasn't moved there were weird quotes in the link. fixed.

Comment: However, Microsoft said that is legacy now:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/symbol-packages

Comment: Yeah, probably they want you use sourcelink or something now. https://github.com/dotnet/sourcelink